# Matlab out of memory on a cvx optimization

Tags: matlab, out-of-memory, ram

I'm running a Matlab to resolve an optimization problem with CVX, and at a certain point, it throws a

```
Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.

Error in cvx_reshape (line 41)
        x = sparse( ii, jj, x, s( 1 ), s( 2 ) );

Error in  *  (line 188)
    z2 = cvx_reshape( z2, [ nA, nz ], tt );

Error in laplacian_learning (line 86)
            Objective = trace(Sk'*Ck*Sk) + param.mu* norm(L_recovered,'fro')
```

The Objective is a CVX object and: Sk is a 64x64 matrix, Ck is a 64x64 matrix and L_recovered is a 76x76 matrix and is the variable I want to learn through the optimization problem together with Ck. 
My PC has 8 GB of RAM DDR3, and an Intel i3 (I know..) ... but the problem I think is the RAM. Which step should I follow to resolve this problem?
Thank you in advance

Comment: It is surprising that a 64x64 matrix gets you out of RAM. Are you sure you haven't made a mistake in your code and are using way bigger matrices instead?

Comment: @AnderBiguri yes, I'm pretty sure. Do you know CVX? In such a case I can edit the post and copy some code of my cvx problem

Comment: In *any* case, to ask in stackoverflow you are required the minimal code that can reproduce the problem. Read [ask] and [mcve]